# How to handle cosine similarity result in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

code:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame([
    ['apple','sweet'],
    ['apple','affordable'],
    ['apple','fruit'],
    ['orange','fruit'],
    ['orange','sour'],
    ['orange','affordable'],
    ['soda','sweet'],
    ['soda','import'],
    ['soda','softdrinks'],
    ['beer','alchohol'],
    ['beer','smooth'],
    ['beer','expensive'],
    ])
df= df.rename(columns={0: "productName", 1: "itemFeatures"})
df2 = pd.crosstab(df['productName'],df['itemFeatures'])
```

I am stuck at handling the cosine result properly, the answer is there, but seem 'weird', need guidance.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
answer = cosine_similarity(df2, df2)
answer2 = pd.DataFrame(answer, columns=df2.index, index=df2.index)

x = input()
y = input()
answer3 = answer2.loc[['{}'.format(x)],['{}'.format(y)]].values[0]
answer4 = float(answer3)
print('Similarity： {:.2f}%'.format(answer4*100))
```

my desired result is able to input the productName and return the top 3 similar items. After input `productName`, how to return top3 highest score item?

thanks

Comment: what is the `cosine_similarity` function you are using ?

Comment: noted, i had add @sklearn.metrics.pairwise

Comment: If you use `answer = pd.DataFrame(answer, columns=df2.index, index=df2.index)` then you can index into the DataFrame with loc: `answer.loc['apple', 'orange'] ` or `answer['apple'].nlargest(3)`

Comment: thanks! can you write as answer? so i can vote as correct answer